# Replace own stdout with a FILE* pointer obtained from popen(3), without using dup(2)

Tags: c, linux, pipe, popen, dup2

In a recent course assignment, we're told to implement a basic shell interpreter with support for at most 1 pipe. For example, the result program should behave mostly identical to a POSIX shell given the following input:

```sh
cat 1.txt | grep abcd
```

(By *at most 1*, it means our program doesn't need to handle the case of multiple pipes, such as `cat | cat | cat`.)

Our teaching assistants listed the following system calls for use:

```
fork  waitpid  execv  system  popen  pclose
```

Let's ignore the fact that only 2 of them are actually *system calls*. The problem I'm having is that I have no idea how I can replace stdin of current process with the `FILE*` pointer returned by popen(3).

There's a special requirement, that I don't want an answer telling me to get the file descriptor with fileno(3) and then dup(2). This is because I have already implemented my own shell (assignment submission) with pipe(2) and dup(2), completely ignoring what our TAs told us. And this is why I want to know how it's possible without fileno(3) then dup(2).

Assuming dup, dup2 and dup3 (GNU) are the same thing (dup searches for the lowest-numbered unused fd, while dup2 closes its second argument when necessary - the primary function is identical - to duplicate a fd).

Comment: What about `fileno()` and `dup2()`?

Comment: @Shawn I was implying `dup` and `dup2` are the same thing. In fact, my implementation used `dup2(write_fd, 1)` or similar.

Comment: You're overthinking it. Open `cat` for read. Open `grep` for write. Read from `cat`, write to `grep`. Done.

Comment: @user3386109 That looks like an answer.

Comment: No idea why `system()` is in this list.

Comment: Are you allowed to use any of the file I/O functions (`fread()`, `fwrite()` for example) in the shell?  You normally don't need an active process in the middle as suggested by @user3386109 — but you're normally able to use `dup2()` and `fileno()`.  If `fread()` and `fwrite()` are permissible, you have a workable solution. There are no standard functions that do the equivalent of `dup2()` but for file streams instead of file descriptors.  I'm not sure if you're allowed to create a suitable function that could be called to do the job of `dup2()` for a file stream; presumably not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't mind anything other than dup/dup2, I just don't want to call dup/2 directly in my code.

Comment: I suspect what they want you to do is call `popen()` twice. Once for the left side of the pipe, once for the right side. Then you read from the first pipe and write to the second pipe in a loop.

Comment: @alk No idea too, maybe those TAs need to learn more

Comment: It looks like your school employs either evil or incompetent teachers. The requirements make no sense. If you are writing a Unix shell, you do these things with `pipe` and `dup2`. No `system` or `popen` or any such nonsense. Teaching students otherwise is wasting their time.